# How in Fortran 77 or in the next standards to do a multi-column out put in a simple calculation, having a Nested loop?

Tags: fortran

I have a simple question concerning the management of the output after running a Fortran code, having a **NESTED LOOP**..
I want to calculate for different **k=1,5,9** the value $\mathbf{Sin(kx)}$ in the range $\mathbf{x=0:2\pi}$ with the step $\mathbf{h=0.01}$.
As the range of $\mathbf{x}$ for all $\mathbf{k}$ is the same, I would like to do an output in a **cal.dat** file as the following (of course without the functions and just number):

$x$ $\quad\qquad\sin(x)$   $\qquad\sin(5x)$    $\qquad\sin(9x)$ 
$0.0$ $\quad\qquad0$ $\qquad\qquad0$ $\quad\qquad\qquad0$
$...$ $\quad\qquad...$ $\qquad\qquad...$ $\quad\qquad\qquad...$


My code is:

> ```
>          program test3
>          real dx,f,x
>          k=1
>          pi=4.0*atan(1.0)
>          open(11,file='sinkx.dat',status='unknown',form='formatted')
>          do  while(k<10)
>          x=0.0
>          dx=0.01
>          do while(x<2*pi)
>          f=sin(k*x) 
>          write(11,1001) x,f
> 1001     format(' ',f9.3,' ',e12.3)
>          x=x+dx
>          enddo
>          k=k+4
>          enddo
>          end
> ```
>
> The questions is that when you run this code, you get the output not in a multi-column out put as desired, but in a two column out put in which first come numbers for the $\mathbf{x}$ range and in the second column the values of $\mathbf{Sin(kx)}$ for different $\mathbf{k=1}$, then $\mathbf{k=5}$ and then $\mathbf{k=9}$.
>   How to write results in a multi-column out put, as I have indicated in the above?
>   I think that the question is in **write** operator rather than in the calculations?
>   Of course, I could write the results in thre different **cal.dat**, but I prefer to write it in a one **dat** file, since the range of $\mathbf{x}$ is the same for all $\mathbf{k}$.

Comment: Welcome to scicomp -- Nice question - only your formatting is a bit off the standards :)

Comment: Thank You @Jan. You are right. I am not the best, but try to be better :)

Comment: Thank you @A-R-M. <br/>What a pitty that I could not realize that first I have to do a loop for $\mathbf{x}$, write it and then do the loop for $\mathbf{k}$ and again write it. Nevertheless, thank you for your help. <br/>But there is a moment I can not understand. If with **advanced='no'** option in the **write** operator, one can do a multiple column, then why did you add the statement **write(11,*)** at the end of the code? I can not understand the role of this line. Could you in 2 or 3 words explain it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with your program. I am not sure why you are expecting it to produce multiple column output in the way that you want. You are looping over *x* for each *k*. You need to switch this nesting first.

As you rightly guessed there is a specifier for the write statement, **advance='no'**, which you can use to not advance to the next line when using formatted output. I have made the changes that would give you the desired formatting. It is slightly *hacky* but it works.

```
program test3
  real dx,f,x
  pi=4.0*atan(1.0)
  open(11,file='sinkx.dat',status='unknown',form='formatted')
  x=0.0
  dx=0.01
  do while(x<2*pi)
    write(11,'(f9.3)',advance='no') x
    k=1
    do  while(k<10)
      f=sin(k*x) 
      write(11,1001,advance='no') f
      k=k+4
    enddo
    x=x+dx
    write(11,*) ' '
  enddo
  1001  format(' ',e12.3)
endprogram
```

Comment: Thank you @A-R-M. What a pitty that I could not realize that first I have to do a loop for $\mathbf{x}$

Comment: @Shariel You are welcome! The statement `write(11,*)' '` is there to print the next _x_  and _f(x)_ on a new line. As the first two `write` statements have `advance=no`,all the output would have been printed on the first line itself (one very long line), if this statement were not present.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest moving to Fortran 90 and using an implied do loop inside the write statement:

```
program test3
    real, parameter :: dx=0.01
    real :: x
    integer :: k
    pi=4.0*atan(1.0)
    open(unit=11,file='sinkx.dat',status='replace',form='formatted')
    x=0.0
    do while(x < 2.0*pi)
        write(unit=11,fmt='(X,F9.3,10(X,E12.3))') &
            x, (SIN(REAL(k)*x),k=1,10,4)
        x=x+dx
    end do
    close(unit=11)
end program test3
```

Edit: Note that this would also work if we replaced the 10 in `fmt='(X,F9.3,10(X,E12.3))'` with any number greater or equal to 3. We could also calculate the number during runtime:

```
program test3
    ...
    integer, parameter :: k_max=10
    character(len=64) :: my_format
    write(my_format,'(A,I0,A)') "(X,F9.3,", 1+(k_max-1)/4, "(X,E12.3))"
    ...
    do while(x < 2.0*pi)
        write(unit=11,fmt=my_format) &
            x, (SIN(REAL(k)*x),k=1,k_max,4)
        x=x+dx
    end do
    ...
end program test3
```